# jQuery UI Sortable + Bootstrap - connectWith is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm building an image tool for my website. Users can sort photos between a area, where photos are visible and where photos are hidden.

http://jsfiddle.net/2r6n9u8m/

In jsfiddle it is working.

But in my code it is not working on my webpage.

When I excluded css and js ... it was working when I excluded the bootstrap.css ... but I still dont know the issue.

```
<div id="photos-show" class="connectedSortable">


        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 1340782121.06.jpg">                           
            <img class="img-thumbnail img-reponsive" src="/1340782121.06.jpg" alt="Foto von dem Inserat" >
        </div>


        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 1340782104.56.jpg">                           
            <img class="img-thumbnail img-reponsive" src="/1340782104.56.jpg" alt="Foto von dem Inserat" >
        </div>


        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 1340782111.74.jpg">                           
            <img class="img-thumbnail img-reponsive" src="/1340782111.74.jpg" alt="Foto von dem Inserat" >
        </div>                      
</div>

<div class=" col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">                            
        <h4>More pictures?</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Click here</button>
</div>



<div class="row">   
        <h2>Photos hidden</h2>
    <div id="photos-hidden" class="connectedSortable">              

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 1401025214.2901.jpg">                         
            <img class="img-thumbnail img-reponsive" src="/1401025214.2901.jpg" alt="Foto von dem Inserat" style="opacity: .5; filter:Alpha(Opacity=50);">
           </div>


        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 1401025216.7008.jpg">                         
            <img class="img-thumbnail img-reponsive" src="/1401025216.7008.jpg" alt="Foto von dem Inserat" style="opacity: .5; filter:Alpha(Opacity=50);">
          </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Made a few fixes, please check.

```
placeholder: "col-xs-2 xs-placeholder",
```

and

```
start: function() {
   $('.xs-placeholder').css('height', $('.connectedSortable .col-xs-2').eq(0).height());
}
```

Also changed col-md-2 to col-xs-2.

http://jsfiddle.net/2r6n9u8m/2/